# How does PHP access properties internally?

Tags: php, c++, pointers, reference

Following up on this documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

> One of the key-points of PHP OOP that is often mentioned is that "objects are passed by references by default". This is not completely true.

> In PHP, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object.

How does this actually work? In C++ for example it seems that the arrow operator implicitly dereferences the pointer and then accesses the properties like when accessing them on the object variable itself.

Here's what I mean:

```
obj->prop
(*obj).prop // equivalent to line above
```

This seems pretty clean. The property is called as the sum of the object-variable-address and the property-offset in both cases.

But how does that work in PHP?
The documentation suggests that the pointer does not store the memory address but rather an "object-identifier". Is accessing properties in PHP a highly abstracted process or does it resolve the object-identifier for the memory address and then access it in a similar way to C++ / Java / etc.?

Answer (score 1):

It's a highly abstracted process, similarity in syntax does not indicate that the code "falls through" to working like C/C++. You can [dive into the code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_object_handlers.c) to see how it works under the covers.

Comment: You generally read a lot that there are no pointers in several (scripting) languages. Take JS for example. However I feel like they all use some sort of pointer. Is it fine if I imagine object access operations by pointers?

Comment: I don't think that's a helpful way to think about all objects in PHP. PHP's pass-by-reference vs. pass-by-value  features provide some pointer-like capabilities, so thinking about all objects as pointers might cause some cognitive dissonance around that. IMO it's more helpful to forget about syntactic similarities with C/C++. I think if you take some time to really wrap your head around PHP's pass-by-reference, you'll come up with an intuitive mental model that works well for you.

Comment: OK, but the quoted document says that object variables aren't references but contain an object-identifier which points to the actual object. While that identifier is not an actual memory address it comes pretty close to the concept of pointers rather than references I think. It explicitly says that it's not an alias.

Comment: I mean, you do you but I don't think it makes sense to even think about how the interpreter is handling things under the covers when writing PHP code. PHP isn't intended to be a wrapper around C (anymore at least, it was closer to that in the early days), and I don't see any reason to think about the language in C terms. I get that people coming from a C background may naturally do that, and it it works for you, great, but IMO it's just overthinking things.